# ignore failed process manager command

Tags: jenkins, sh, pm2

I have Jenkins file with next command:

```
sh "pm2 delete some-process"
sh "pm2 start some-new-process"
```

If there are no 'some-process' running, this command fails and next command doesn't runs. How I can ignore fail command end switch to next command?

Answer (score 0):

Use a `try {} catch() {}` block or a `catchError()` step. Like this:

```
catchError(buildResult: 'SUCCESS', stageResult: 'SUCCESS') {
    sh "pm2 delete some-process"
}
sh "pm2 start some-new-process"
```

```
try {
    sh "pm2 delete some-process"
}
catch(Exception e) {
    print("Error stopping pm2: ${e}")
}
sh "pm2 start some-new-process"
```

Best regards!